# Summarizing a list of Channels

Tags: javascript, summarize

Heres the problem I have:

**Turn this string input:** "Ch 471: PRO BM R #5,Ch 472: PRO BM R #4,Ch 473: PRO BM R #3,Ch 481: PRO BM L #5,Ch 482: PRO BM L #4,Ch 484: PRO BM L #3"

**Into this string output:**
Ch 471-473: PRO BM R #3-5
Ch 481-484: PRO BM L #3-5

Im attempting to write a function in JavaScript that essentially filters through a string of channels separated by commas of x amounts and then summarizes them in the format above.  In the example above there are 6 different channels with positions and units.

The deciding/grouping factor are the positions *(In the above example, PRO BM R and PRO BM L)* - So finding all the channels and units on one position and then summarizing that info.

Heres details on nomenclature:

- Channels = Ch 471
- Positions = PRO BM R
- Units = #5

What I have tried so far, and what Im assuming I would need to do is use several loops to `split()` the data

- First by comma
- Then by :
- Then by # sign

Then push the data into 3 different arrays

1. Channel Array
2. Position Array
3. Unit Array

Then filter through each array to find unique values, max values, etc. I just can't wrap my head around this problem though?

Any pointers, example code, or assistance of any kind is welcomed!

Answer (score 0):

I think using regex would help you better separate your components: `Ch (?<channel>\d+): (?<position>(?:\w|\s)+) #(?<units>\d+)`

Here's a starting point for parsing your text:

```js
const regex = /Ch (?<channel>\d+): (?<position>(?:\w|\s)+) #(?<units>\d+)/g;

const inputString = "Ch 471: PRO BM R #5,Ch 472: PRO BM R #4,Ch 473: PRO BM R #3,Ch 481: PRO BM L #5,Ch 482: PRO BM L #4,Ch 484: PRO BM L #3";

const groups = {};

[...inputString.matchAll(regex)].forEach(a => (groups[a.groups.position] ||= []).push({ channel: +a.groups.channel, units: +a.groups.units }));

console.log(groups);
```

You can then manipulate this data to create a string.

Comment: Yeah! This is super super helpful! Still figuring out how to run through that object you created, but its a great start!

Would you try to use a forEach() loop on the Object after transforming it to an array to start parsing through the regex created object?

Comment: Thank you for your help! One question - In your code in the [...inputString . . . ] portion you have a `||=` which is giving me an error in one of the environments im running it in.   Do you have any idea whats going on?

Comment: @ScottWeir yes, you could try using forEach, or experiment with whatever works to achieve the result you want; and also `a ||= b` is new syntax, you can replace it with `a || (a = b)`

Comment: Interesting - I did finish my project and am getting the result expected, except for the new syntax is still reading as error.  Even when I replaced it with equivalent old syntax then I get the error: error: Uncaught TypeError: (groups[a.groups.position] || (groups[a.groups.position] === [])).push is not a function

Comment: it's a single `=` sign