# Filtering through / Summarizing a list of numbers in an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, math

Looking for some help in javascript.  Heres the problem

Heres my input:

```
[
{channel: 471, unit: 1},
{channel: 472, unit: 2},
{channel: 473, unit: 3},
{channel: 474, unit: 5},
{channel: 479, unit: 6}
]
```

And here is what I am looking for as an output:

```
Ch: 471-474, 479 #1-3,5-6
```

So essentially looping through an array of objects to summarize numeric values in a sorted manner. I was originally using a `math.max()` and `math.min()` method to find max and min numbers to display like this:

```
Ch: 471-479
```

But that is not accounting for the fact that there is no 475,476,477, or 478.
I was also using an Object.keys() method to turn the objects into arrays to then filter through using `math.max` and `min`

Any idea how I would do something like this? Is it even possible? Any help is appreciated!

*for the sake of being thorough, here is my entire code so far where I am stuck*

```
const regex = /Ch (?<channel>\d+): (?<position>(?:\w|\s)+) #(?<units>\d+)/g;

const inputString = "Ch 471: PRO BM R #5,Ch 472: PRO BM R #4,Ch 473: PRO BM R #3,Ch 481: PRO BM L #5,Ch 482: PRO BM L #4,Ch 484: PRO BM L #3";

const groups = {};

[...inputString.matchAll(regex)].forEach(a => (groups[a.groups.position] ||= []).push({ channel: +a.groups.channel, units: +a.groups.units }));

console.log(groups);

const keys = Object.keys(groups);
console.log(keys)
keys.forEach((key,index)=>{
  let maxChannelNum = Math.max.apply(Math, groups[key].map(function(x) {return x.channel;}))
  let minChannelNum = Math.min.apply(Math, groups[key].map(function(x) {return x.channel;}))
  let maxUnitNum = Math.max.apply(Math, groups[key].map(function(x) {return x.units;}))
  let minUnitNum = Math.min.apply(Math, groups[key].map(function(x) {return x.units;}))
  console.log(`Ch: ${minChannelNum}-${maxChannelNum} ${key} #${minUnitNum}-${maxUnitNum}`)
})
```

Comment: *"Here is my input..."*: that input is not structured in the same way as the input you have in your code. In fact, that code has a single string as input. But even the `groups` object derived from it, does not have the same structure (it is not an array). Can you bring your text and code in harmony?

Comment: Your code seems to give significance to strings like "PRO BM R", yet your question seems to ignore that. I'm not sure what you want here.

Comment: It does give significance to that for sure, see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70502941/summarizing-a-list-of-channels/70503245#70503245) for more explanation

Comment: Explanation should be embedded in the question. And could you resolve the inconsistency in the input format?

Answer (score 0):

First off, you need to clearly define how exactly you want to display your number ranges and what the minimum interval between each number is - for example, if you're expecting the possibility of floating point numbers (say, 471, 472, 472.5, 473...), you'd have to re-define what counts as part of an interval (for example 471-473) and what breaks an interval (in the aforementioned case that would be a 475).

As long as you can define what counts as part of a range and at what point you need to begin a new one, I don't think there is anything stopping you from the naive approach of simply sorting all of your datasets according to their numerical value; in this case giving you the two sets

```
471, 472, 473, 474, 479
```

and

```
1, 2, 3, 5, 6
```

and then simply looping through them, selecting the first entry of each data set as the beginning of the range and defining the end of a range once it breaks the condition of your range - in this case, being larger than the preceding number by more than one.

I'm sure there are more optimal ways of achieving this, but does anything speak against this approach outright?

Comment: Thanks for the input! Here is my original post with more context [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70502941/summarizing-a-list-of-channels/70503245#70503245), but my intervals for channels are ALL whole numbers while my unit numbers can actually even start with letters like L5 or 0a

Comment: @ScottWeir I think you may be trying to do too many things in one place. You should try cleaning your dataset of things like that and standardizing it to just numbers before you attempt splitting it into ranges.

Comment: I wish I could clean the data set more - but not entirely sure how?

Answer (score 0):

You could take all numbbers, combine continuous numbers and join them to strings.

```js
const
    update = (array, value) => {
        const
            last = array[array.length - 1],
            lastValue = last?.[1] || last?.[0];

        if (lastValue + 1 === value) last[1] = value;
        else array.push([value]);
    },
    input = "Ch 471: PRO BM R #5,Ch 472: PRO BM R #4,Ch 473: PRO BM R #3,Ch 481: PRO BM L #5,Ch 482: PRO BM L #4,Ch 484: PRO BM L #3",
    temp = input
        .split(',')
        .map(s => s.match(/\d+/g))
        .reduce((r, [a, b]) => {
            update(r[0], +a);
            update(r[1], +b);
            return r;
        }, [[], []])
        .map(a => a.map(b => b.join('-')).join()),
    result = `Ch: ${temp[0]} #${temp[1]}`

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Unfortunately the logged result is only: Ch: 471-473,481-482,484 #5,4,3,5,4,3

Which doesn't quite get to the output I was looking for

Comment: what result do you expect?